# Checking multiple fields: continue an IF loop if a try/except criteria is successful

Tags: python

Still very much a programming learner and I've found a gaping hole in my understanding so I'd appreciate any feedback on this. I have a Django-based HTML form that allows you to define additional drivers to a vehicle routing problem. It is critical that any error in the format of every input field is captured and rejected before it is stored. My approach is a series of `if` and `elif` clauses for a prototype list of expected errors, and part of it works just fine. However, I get to a test of whether I can parse a field into a datetime object using a `try` / `except` block and my `if` / `elif` chain terminates on a successful `try` (because `elif` is satisfied). The problem is, I still need to run the remaining tests on success, and using `continue` does not work on any indentation I can find.

I cannot think of a `while` loop or `for` loop to achieve the same effect. I tried putting it in a function, as listed below, but that was clutching at straws.

I have two questions 1) Am I well off-the-mark on how to check data entry; I'd love direction on this? 2) Do I have to break this down into multiple, separate tests to return the error of `driverinfomessage`?

The barebones is below. On a success of `starttime` test the loop ends and never checks `endtime` (EDIT: Although I'm aware that the `continue` statements will throw an error; they're there as expected behaviour)

```
def is_timestamp(stamp_string):
    is_time = False
    try:
        stamp_string.datetime.datetime.strptime(stamp_string, "%H:%M")
        is_time = True
    except:
        is_time = False
    return is_time

if drivername == '':
    driverinfomessage = "No driver name"

elif starttime != '':
    test = is_timestamp(starttime)
    if test:
        continue
    else:
        driverinfomessage = "Invalid start time"

elif endtime != '':
    test = is_timestamp(endtime)
    if test:
        continue
    else:
        driverinfomessage = "invalid end time"
```

I can post more of the function if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read any of the [Django Forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/)? This isn't normally done in a view. As for your `if/elif/else` problem the solution would be to break them up into multiple `if` blocks, but I wouldn't recommend that here.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I have read the documents and followed their entire tutorial. However, I feel this is a fundamental Python question, not related to Django - the fact that it is a HTML form would not change the objective; try parse a datetime and, on success, continue the rest of the tests. The Django part I mentioned was more to give the code context.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist and the reason I added context is that there could be a paradigm I am completely missing here when dealing with free-hand text inputs to multiple fields. My approach feels dumb, even without the errors in the code.

Comment: If you do it the (correct) Django way, you don't end up constructing a giant if tree in your view, and this problem doesn't arise. Dealing with HTML forms is pretty far away from fundamental Python, which is why we have frameworks like Django. Like I said, every condition in an `if/elif/else` tree must be mutually exclusive. If they're not, you need more than one.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist You are absolutely correct. I am not doing it the correct Django way but treating this more as a Tkinter interface. The backend is a convoluted web of code communicating with a Java routing server and the form is not writing to an SQlite DB but rather to a config file for that algorithm. So the answer is multiple `if/elif/else` trees I suppose.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Quick question. I'm on a super-tight deadline and this seemed the easiest way to display a message to the user trying to add an invalid driver. But if I was to use sqlite3; If the input field is set as TEXT expecting `%H:%M`, how would you detect a false string entry without a `datetime` check cluttering up views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Throw exceptions out of your main code**, handle them outside.

In Python you often code the main happy scenario as if all goes nice
and let exceptions to be thrown in the case of problems.

The `check_and_process` it example of such "happy code".

The calling function (`test_it` here) is using `try` - `except` pair (there can
be even more `except` section), each expecting known exceptions.

This way your code is kept clean and still is able to handle exceptional
situation.

```
class FieldException(Exception):
    pass


def get_timestamp(fieldname, stamp_string):
    try:
        return stamp_string.datetime.date.strptime(stamp_string, "%H:%M")
    except:
        msg = "Field {fieldname} expects time in HH:MM format."
        raise FieldException(msg.format(fieldname=fieldname))


def check_and_process(driver_name, start_time_str, end_time_str):
    if not driver_name:
        raise FieldException("Driver name is required")
    start_time = get_timestamp("start time", start_time_str)
    end_time = get_timestamp("end time", end_time_str)

    print("processing {}, {} and {}".format(driver_name, start_time, end_time))


def test_it():
    try:
        check_and_process("Johny", "12:34", "23:55")
        # check_and_process("Johny", "12:34", "25:62")
        # check_and_process("", "12:34", "25:62")
    except FieldException as e:
        print(e.msg)
```

Note, that it is very important to catch and handle all expected exceptions and
follow these rules:

- never use `pass` as the only content in `except` block as it hides problems you shall discover (and later resolve)
- learn, what expected types of exceptions can be thrown and catch those and process as needed.
- let other (unexpected) exception to raise and break your program. It will be the fastest way to correction of it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your detailed explanation, this goes far beyond what I expected in terms of the correct way to handle these types of exception :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be aiming at something like the following:

```
if drivername == '':
    driverinfomessage = "No driver name"
elif not is_timestamp(starttime):
    driverinfomessage = "Invalid start time"
elif not is_timestamp(endtime):
    driverinfomessage = "invalid end time"
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer that gives me a lot of feedback on exception handling which addresses my first question and hopefully makes me a better programmer :) However, this answer does connect the dots on what I was trying to do so I have upvoted. Thanks.